# Rails 3 most effective way to test if a value exists in a unqiue has_many :through relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, has-many-through

These are the models in question

```
SkillProgession
belongs_to :skill
belongs_to :user

User
has_many :skill_progressions
has_many :skills, :through => :skill_progressions

def has_progression?(skill)
   SkillProgression.where(:skill_id => skill.id, :user_id => id).first
end

Skill
has_many :skill_progressions
has_many :users, :through => :skill_progressions
```

In the application a user can have several skills, and a skill can be related to several users. It's important that there's just **one** relation between each user and skill, as we want to store additional information at a further stage (i.e. 'competance' or whatever).

I have an index to ensure that the database won't allow duplicate rows (is this really necessary btw?)

```
add_index :skill_progressions, [:skill_id, :user_id ], :unique => true, :name => 'by_skill_and_user'
```

This relationship is added when something **external to both models happens** (a user submits an answer to a task related to the current skill) - demonstrated in this controller code:

```
TaskController

def answer
   skill = Skill.find(params[:skill_id])
   @task = skill.tasks.find(params[:id])       
   unless current_user.has_progression?(skill)
     current_user.add_skill(skill, "placeholder")
   end
end
```

Now, this seems rather **hacky**, and I'd like a way to make it cleaner. I guess I could use the following code in the controller

```
skill_progression = SkillProgression.find_by_user_id(current_user.id)
current_user.skill_progressions.include? skill_progression
```

But would this be any more efficient or elegant way to do it?

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated :-) Even if I need to rethink my entire design approach, I just want it to be elegant!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add a validation in the skill_progression model

```
validates :skill_id, uniqueness: { scope: :user_id }
```

Adding this will prevent creating of 2 skill_progress records that has the same `user_id` and `skill_id`. Be warned though that there are a lot of ways to get around this.

Comment: Thank you very much for answering - would this be the most 'Rails' way to approach this problem? Also, the way I would see if a skill_progression already exists would be to try and create a new one, and then catching the validation error if one exists?